# How to use decorators inside namespace: MobX

Tags: javascript, mobx

I use MobX in my client-side code like this:

```
<script src="/js/mobx.umd.js"></script>
<script src="/js/mobx-react/index.min.js"></script>
```

Now When I want to actually use MobX like below, it doesn't work, i.e. my client-side user-interface doesn't react to changes of observable variables:

```
const action=window.mobx.action
const observable=window.mobx.observable

class Store {

    @observable isLoggedIn=false;
    @action setIsLoggedIn=(tf)=>{this.isLoggedIn=tf}
}
```

I wonder how I can actually use `window.mobx.action` and `window.mobx.observable` with ES6.

---

Previously I was using MobX with NPM like below, and it was working fine:

```
import { action, observable } from 'mobx'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decorators are only supported through transpilation by babel / typescript. For ES5 syntax see https://mobx.js.org/best/decorators.html

Answer (score 0):

```
class Store {
   isLoggedIn = observable(false);
   setIsLoggedIn= action((tf)=>{this.isLoggedIn=tf});
}
```